# Updating async storage/data store in real time

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await, state, persistence

I have a react native application where a user can edit a text which is stored in react state. I would like to implement autosaving so that user input is persisted in real time.

I have replaced my state with async persistence but have found that I am running into a race condition:

- My parent component fetches the text from persistence.
- The user inputs new text, which triggers a callback to update the given text with the new content.
- If the user inputs text too quickly, before the persistence has updated and my parent component has fetched the new, updated text, the next async update is triggered on the old text, causing a conflict.

In particular, this happened with AWS DataStore. I have not tried using async storage, but given it also uses async/await I imagine I will run into the same problem.

A hacky approach would be updating at longer intervals but I'm assuming whatever interval I set will be long enough that each async update completes before the next. It's also more complicated as I have to keep local state which contains what the user sees while syncing that with the async storage/DataStore in the background.

Is there a nice way to replace react state with a persisted version that doesn't require a load of extra logic handling async race conditions? In an ideal world, some sort of `usePersistedState` hook which manages this all for me, exposing the exact same behaviour as `useState`?

---

To give an example of the race condition, say the text is `a`, and I type in `b` followed by `c`:

- First DataStore update: `a` + `b`
- (**Expected** second DataStore update `ab` + `c`)
- **Actual** second DataStore update if input is too fast: `a` + `c`
- DataStore result is some conflict, e.g. merging both updates to produce `abac`

Comment: HI. Showing the code might help us out

Comment: thats what redux and redux-persist for. redux is global state and its updating in a realtime, combine with redux-persit middleware you can store your redux state into async storage, so you get a local storage that can be access in a realtime on any screen

Comment: Try react-native-mmkv. It is a lot faster, so maybe could fix your issue.